# Best way to store images from bytes and get from cache?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am making requests to my API to fetch images, it returns the bytes for the image. So what I do is I assign `response.bodyBytes` to a `Uint8List`.

Then I can display the image in a `Image.memory()` widget.

How do I store large amounts of images in the phone memory, and check if it exists in memory before making more requests to my API?

Comment: In short: you want to cache the images?

Comment: @HEllRZA Yes that's right.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I was using a Flask for my API and I used `send_file()` to send it as a rendered image instead, now I can use the standard **cached_network_image** as a URL. I just had to change it from POST to GET, and use params instead of headers so I could use the `imageURL` property.